# How do I remove, more than one at a time, design package from the design package listings in Delphi 11 Enterprise?

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-11-alexandria

I've not ever had this problem in the past when migrating from one version to the next, but today this is an issue!

I just migrated my settings from Delphi 10.4.2 Enterprise to Delphi 11 Enterprise and now it tries to load all the design packages for Delphi 10.4.2 along with the design packages for Delphi 11.

I would like to just go to the list and select all I want to remove and click remove button, but for some reason Delphi is setup so that you can only remove one at a time and it will ask you if your sure you want to remove it!  That's only nice once things are going, but right now I need to remove over 100+ design packages that I don't need without going one by one.

I've been searching the folders for text, config, idesettings, and other files for a way to do it faster and I'm just frustrated.  Maybe I didn't look hard enough or something?

I hope that I don't have to do each one... one by one.  Does anyone know a quicker way?

Much Thanks in Advance and sincerely,

Greg T.

Comment: The installed packages are recorded in the registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\21.0\Known IDE Packages, so you could save a copy of that and paste what you want over that.

Comment: I've noticed that nasty behavior too. Never happened with previous versions of the Migration Tool. D11 .. licensing issues, now this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of installed packages is stored in the Registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\<version>\`, which has "Known Packages" and "Known IDE Packages" subkeys.